# Can I make Text Field accept filtered_html?

Tags: entities, input-formats

I have a content type where a field is the common name for a USA president. In examing a legacy database I'm importing some presidents have (simple) HTML in their name. For example `Dwight Eisenhower <i>Ike</i>`.

I would like to support this on a content type field `field_people_common_name` which is a `textfield` created in the Field UI.

Following these directions:

- https://www.drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#text_format
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1087468

I've created a simple form alter hook to allow the input format of `filtered_html` on this form element:

```
function prez_people_form_people_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
  $form['field_people_common_name']['und'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'text_format';
  $form['field_people_common_name']['und'][0]['value']['#base_type'] = 'textfield';
  $form['field_people_common_name']['und'][0]['value']['#format'] = 'filtered_html';
  $form['field_people_common_name']['und'][0]['value']['#settings'] = array('text_processing ' => '1');
}
```

This appears to well, work or function:

[image]

But upon previewing the edit I get these errors:

```
Warning: mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in drupal_strlen() (line 482 of ../htdocs/includes/unicode.inc).

Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1583 of ../htdocs/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1583 of ../htdocs/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

Any idea how to get this to work. I'm trying to avoid embedding a `text_area` for simple textfield value (a name will **never** require a massive textarea .... yes I know I could make the textarea 1 row tall ....)

Comment: Is the field showing up in your preview? It sounds like something quirky with your install. I've had field configurations like this and I've never hit this error before.

Comment: Yes it is but it's blank. It's not a problem with my installation. Maybe I have to alter the field widget instead ...

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the problem. I thought you'd already performed the solution that Thomas4019 posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use hook_form_alter to allow the user to specify an input format for a textfield. On the content type page, you can edit a fields settings and there is an option titled "Text Processing" that you will want to use instead.

[image]

Then when I look at my node form I see the following:

[image]

Comment: Sure, I'll buy this as an answer. For this project I'm migrating a large legacy DB into drupal -- re-configuring the field structure until it's right and re-importing everything... sounds like a PITA. But, after making the change I guess it's the only way to go as it appears to add a `filter` column to the DB schema.

Comment: Yeah, the features module can help avoid some of that pain, but for just doing a migration it's overkill. The migrate module also might help, but it's pretty opinionated and has a learning curve.

Comment: I'm using both those modules :). I forgot a text field could have an input format -- I was hoping for a programmatic solution to altering the field to enable/store the filter type. It's a pain updating features and re-running migrations.